# Probability in a non-symmetric binary channel

Tags: probability, bayesian

My question is as follows:

In a nonsymmetric binary channel, $0$ and $1$ are transmitted independently in the proportion of $1:4$. If a $0$ was transmitted, we will receive $0$ with a probability of $0.9$. If a $1$ transmitted, we will receive $1$ with a probability of $0.95$.

a) What is the probability that a received symbol is "$1$"?

b) A "$1$" has been received what is the probability that a "$1$" actually been transmitted?

c) A "$0$" has been received what is the probability that a "$0$" actually been transmitted?

I found below answers but I am not sure:

a)

$P(R_1)=\frac{1}{5}*P(T_0|R_1)+ \frac{4}{5}*P(T_1|R_1)$=$\frac{1}{5}*0.1+ \frac{4}{5}*0.95=0.78$

Comment: For a) I found 0.78. I suppose bayes will be sufficient but I am not sure

Comment: @sajjad Show your work, please! Thanks.

Comment: Please put it in your question

Comment: Please press the "edit" link and add that to the actual post. This is part of what we want from good question posts here. How far you've gotten on (b) and (b) would also be nice if you said something about.

Comment: I am editing... for part B and C (as they are similar) I have no answer

Comment: Part $(a)$ looks good

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(a)$ looks good

**Hint** for $(b)$

Use Bayes' Theroem:

$$\begin{align*}
P(\text{1 transmitted | 1 received})
&=\frac{P(\text{1 transmitted} \cap 1\text{ received})}{P(\text{1 received})}\\\\
\end{align*}$$

where $P(\text{1 received})$ is what you solved correctly in part $(a)$

**Hint** for $(c)$

This calculation is similar noting that $$P(\text{0 received})=1-P(\text{1 received})$$

Comment: Thank you. I am trying right now

Comment: For $B$ if found this: $P(T_1|R_1)= \frac{P(T_1 \cap R_1)}{P(R_1)}= \frac{P(R_1|T_1)*P(T_1)}{P(R_1)}= \frac{0.95*4/5}{0.78}=0.97$

Comment: That's correct!

Comment: with same noting I found : $P(T_0|R_0)=0.81$

Thank you for hint.

Comment: Yes, except it rounds to $0.82$